# MatDatepicker with German locale doesn't work properly. Maybe bug?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to format date through a directive using Angular Reactive Forms but with German locale the MatDatepicker seems not to work as wanted.

In my `DateDirective` I have built the method below:

```js
   public ngOnInit(): void {
      const control = this.ngControl.control;
      if (control) {
         control.setValue(Parser.parseDate(control.value, this.locale), { emitEvent: false });
         control.valueChanges.subscribe(newDate => {
            newDate = Parser.parseDate(newDate, this.locale);
            control.setValue(newDate, { emitEvent: false });
         });
      }
   }
```

If I choose a date from the datepicker, it works fine. For example, I choose on the datepicker the 19th of March, 2021 and on the form field is shown the output of `19.3.2021`. But if I write the same value directly in the field, the value of `newDate` is `null`. I have noticed that when I write the date in the input field, the datepicker parses it as `mm.dd.yyyy`. Has anyone any idea about how to get rid of this bug/issue without having to override the `NativeDateAdapter`?

Thank you!